# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Pins#index Showing /app/app/views/pins/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I git pushed heroku master for my project from github, but when I do heroku open it says

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Pins#index

Showing /app/app/views/pins/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pins" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"pins"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"pins"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum


Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <%= render 'pages/home' %>
2: 
3: <div id="pins">
4:   <%= render @pins %>
5: </div>
6: 
7: <%= will_paginate @pins %>
```

Can someone help? It works fine locally, but I get the app to deploy on Heroku. Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Comment: It's working fine locally, just not on heorku so I guess I did.

Comment: OK, but did you migrate the db or load your schema on Heroku?

Comment: Sorry, I am such a newby, do you mind showing me how? much appreciated.

Comment: @acts_as_geek - I got it to work now, thanks for your migrate the db comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pins" does not exist`,

means that the table is missing. You have to migrate the database on `Heroku`

After you push to `Heroku`, you can do `heroku run rake db:migrate`